# Reproducing the predictions of random forest regression

Tags: random-forest

I am carrying out a study that compares different models for predicting biomass of plants. Out of all the models that I have compared, I found Random forest to perform the best. If I need to reproduce the predictions with the same model but different training and testing data, are there any parameters or equations that would tell me how these predictions were made like the equations obtained from Multiple Linear Regression (MLR) so that I don't have to set and run the model again on new data to predict the biomass?
I am aware of the fact that random forest regression does not give any equation as the output is given after comparing many decision trees.

Comment: If you have new training data, then you need to train a new model (or just ignore the new training data, but it sounds like you don’t want to do that), and that would be the case  for a linear regression, too.

Comment: Yes @Dave, I don't want to train a new model. I want to use the same model with new data if its possible.